# Authentication failed during install

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-windows

I just download Ubuntu One 3.0.1 for Windows and got the `Authentication failed during install`error. But I can login by http. And when I try to reset my pass client it said `Sorry we did not recognize the email address`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
I removed the folder `xdg` from `%User Profile%\AppData\Local` (shut down all ubuntuone processes to be able to delete it).
After that open the Ubuntu One Control Panel and continue the installation.